# how to deploy custom helm charts using brigade?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm been reading the [tutorials](https://github.com/Azure/brigade) but could not find details on how to deploy custom helm charts. I want to replace our existing JenkineFile deployment with brigade.js but could not figure it how.

let say I want to deploy two helm charts by passing key values, by changing the key and values only but doesn't need to build the docker images as they already exist and just have to deploy helm chart in the kubernetes cluster. I appreciate if you any help me with it?

*Example:*

In JenkinFile I have the following stage step, I would like to test it with Brigade

```
    stage('Staging Deployment') {
      when {
        expression { env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' }
      }

      environment {
        RELEASE_NAME = 'seanmeme-staging'
        SERVER_HOST = 'staging.seanmeme.k8s.prydoni.us'
      }

      steps {
        sh '''
          helm upgrade --install --namespace staging $RELEASE_NAME ./helm/seanmeme --set image.tag=$BUILD_ID,ingress.host=$SERVER_HOST
        '''
      }
      steps {
        sh '''
          helm upgrade --install --namespace staging $RELEASE_NAME ./helm/seanmeme2 --set image.tag=$BUILD_ID,ingress.host=$SERVER_HOST
        '''
      }
}
```